# Why there isn't a feature that lets any user on SO to request other user to answer their question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I browse through other questions to find my answer, sometimes I'll find answers similar to what I'm looking for, and though they don't exactly answer my question, the author might be able to do so. Could we have a feature on SO that will let me request that another user answer my question, in case I find someone who could potentially answer my question?

Answer (score 10):

This feature would not be very constructive.

If this feature was included, it would be a problem for the high-reputation users. And there is no need for this kind of feature. Questions get answers in just a few minutes in 90% of cases.

And there's always chat.

Comment: user will have their setting to allow requests. then only the users who have kept their setting to allow, can receive request. its up to you whether you want request or not.....and chat is not allowed for low reputation users

Comment: @vikasdevde but its very low its just the 20 reputation just one or two good answer get you

Comment: there should also be a feature that the high rep users, who are closing questions, because of duplicate question, they should post the question, which according to them is duplicate of....isn't that unfair with low rep users?

Comment: no its not unfair not at all ... how would you like if a user just make the changes which is not good ... or upload some thing vulgar ..

Comment: what if it isn't vulgar? is this question contains anything vulgar? they can at least post a comment with the link to that duplicate question.

Comment: its not about you its about the other who really not much appreciate  the stackoverlow

Comment: @vikas when closing a question as a duplicate, you *do* have to specify which question it is a duplicate of. The information is at the top of the question

Comment: @vikasdevde: so your solution to not being allowed to so much as enter a chat room is to instead be allowed to directly poke any user of your liking? Right. You haven't thought this one through, I'm afraid.